# Sending an HTTP POST with header form-data request on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

I am calling odata post api having HTTP header filed is "form-data". Below is my code :-

```
NSURL *restURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:restURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod: getorpost];
    if (jsonData != nil) {
                [request setValue:@"application/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

         [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    }

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
```

And i am getting below response:-

Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details

But, it is working fine in Postman. Can anyone please suggest where is the fault in my code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_str];
NSLog(@"%@",datastring);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSMutableData *requestBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[datastring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestBody length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestBody];
httpResponse=[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc]init];
receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ calling with datastring: %@", url, datastring);
}
```

**delegates**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {

     httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
     NSLog(@"%d", httpResponse.statusCode);
      NSLog(@"%@",[httpResponse description]);

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[receivedData appendData:data];
 }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
httpResponse=[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSError *error;


NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"retVal=%@",retVal);
}
```

Comment: what is your return string ?

Comment: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details

Comment: You can mail me the url along with data string my email : reshmimajumder1@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
NSMutableDictionary *postData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[postData setObject:uid forKey:@"id"];
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonInputString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR URL "]];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSDictionary *jsonDict;
if (responseData != nil)
{
    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"jsonDoct == %@",jsonDict);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"RESONPSE IS NULL");
}

if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
    }
    }
```